# How to Handle python script errors and sending them by email

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python.

I have a Python script that grabs some information from the internet and then inserts in a database. I want to run it with cron daily and have the script send me an email each day after it is done.

I already have the email part figured out and it is working for sending the elapsed time and the total records inserted in the database, like this:

at the start of the script:

```
records_inserted = 0
t1_start = time.perf_counter()
```

and at the end of the script:

```
t1_stop = time.perf_counter()

msg = EmailMessage()

msg.set_content("Total elapsed time: %.1f [min]" % ((t1_stop-t1_start)/60) + 
"\n\nThe total number of records inserted in the database was: " + 
str(records_inserted))

email_from = “xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
email_to = “xxxxx@xxxx.com"
gmail_password = “xxxxxx”

msg['From'] = email_from
msg['To'] = email_to
msg['Subject'] = “Script executed"

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_from, gmail_password)
server.send_message(msg)

server.quit()
```

Now, if something in the webpages where I'm getting the content from breaks or changes or there is any error for any reason, I would like to see the errors also in that daily email.

What would be the best way to handle and store(maybe an array) in case there would be one or several errors during execution, and have the error number and description written as part of the email body so I am aware as soon as possible and can take a look and correct as necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: You're already working with a DB, so you could log errors into the DB and retrieve them in your email function.

Comment: thanks @MikeScotty but it's any potential Python errors that I would like to know about and see them in the daily email if there would be any

Comment: you could just wrap all the code that 'does the stuff' into a `try:` `except Exception as _ex:` and attach `repr(_ex)` to your mail

Comment: thanks @fernandezcuesta this works exactly as I needed and the error/s are included in the email body, but no longer are shown in the terminal window where I am running the script from while coding it, not sure why. Any way to continue showing the errors in the terminal window as well as including it in the email(this is already working). Thanks"

Comment: Just `print(repr(_ex))` or use [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

Comment: thank you @fernandezcuesta , that one was so obvious that I missed it :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @fernandezcuesta in the comments is working nicely for me.

I wrappped all the code that 'does the stuff' into a `try: except Exception as _ex:` and attach `repr(_ex)` to my mail